# PHP from command line

Tags: php, command-line

I am trying to use some of the scripts on this site

http://www.tubekit.org/tools.php

As you can see under the Usage section it gives you some arguments to put into the command line

```
php extractYTVideoURLs.php yturls.txt mylist.txt
```

I have downloaded the extract php file and made the 2 text files yet I only get this answer in the command line.

```
c:\php>php C:/Users/extractYTVideoURLs.php yturls.txt my
list.txt

Warning: fopen(yturls.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
C:\Users\extractYTVideoURLs.php on line 21

Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Users\extractYTVideoURLs.php on line 24

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Users\
extractYTVideoURLs.php on line 52
```

Comment: so do you have a yturls.txt file? The first warning is very clear that you don't, and the rest of the script is simply failing because you haven't provided proper input

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear. On line 21 of `C:\Users\extractYTVideoURLs.php` the code calls `fopen()` on a file called `yturls.txt` which it can't find.  Where is this file?  Does it exist at all?

It's generally best practice to reference a file with a fully-qualified path name.  Note that you're currently in the directory `c:\php` so if that file isn't in the current working directory then just referencing it by name isn't going to find it.  You'll need to reference the file by where it's located.  Potentially something like this:

```
php C:/Users/extractYTVideoURLs.php C:/Path/to/yturls.txt C:/Path/to/mylist.txt
```

Comment: I've moved the file and that has made it easier to link to thanks very much.

Now this is coming up

    Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\tubekit\connect.ph
    p on line 13

This is the code in `connect.php` it's referring to, I can't find anything wrong.

    $dbh = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password") or die("Cannot connect to the      database: ". mysql_error());